# I have problems with a proxy curl php

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I have used the (proxy curl php) and I link it with my private domain . But I have problem when I use it to open the first page it's work very well but when I transition between the page to other pages the proxy curl php link change to the the original website link.

How can I keep the link with the proxy curl php for all the pages that I  want to open it ?

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$proxy_ip = "192.157.252.175";
$proxy_port = "8800";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36";

function get_page ( $url, $proxy_ip, $proxy_port, $username, $password, $user_agent, $timeout=20)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,  $user_agent);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $username.":".$password);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip.":".$proxy_port);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    $error = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    if(strlen($html) > 0){
        return $html ;
    } else {
    return $error;
    };
}
echo get_page ($url, $proxy_ip, $proxy_port, $username, $password, $user_agent);
```

Comment: All your script is doing is downloading the HTML and sending it to the end user. It is never going to act as a continuous proxy server

Comment: @Devon Ok. Can you please help me to fix it.

Comment: @Devon ????????

Comment: Like I said, it will **never** work that way with this method.  There is nothing to fix here, continous proxies aren't designed to work this way.  Do some more research into your problem and please don't overuse @ mentions